# Where is python2 if python points to python3?

Tags: python, windows

I installed python3 first on my PC. Now `python` launches python3 in a command prompt. When I tried to run a node app with a python2 dependency, I got an error about syntax (it was using the old print syntax):

```
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: 
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.EXE -c import 
sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
```

But I don't know how to make python point to python2.

Comment: Windows uses a PATH variable, although I don't use Windows all that often anymore, so I can't remember exactly where to find it -- but you will want to ensure that the python2 path is in the PATH before the python3.exe...

Comment: To make python point to python2, go to `python2` directory and copy `python2.exe` as `python` in the same directory, then add this folder to `PATH`

Comment: This is an OS question.  You need to search for your Python2 installation -- likely under the Programs\Python folder -- and either alter your PATH variable to point there, or create an alias (shortcut) for python2.  See your OS documentation for how to handle those variables.

Comment: @kojiro - this is the right answer. It was the ORDER of the path variables

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your Windows environment variable to point to the python you want to use.

That's most likely where node is going to find the path for a usable python.exe.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the env variable

[similar question reference](https://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-do-i-add-python-to-the-windows-path)

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution: Never run `python`. The Windows solution, assuming Python 3 was installed with administrative privileges (so it could install [the Python launcher](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/)), is to run:

```
 py -2
```

to run Python 2, and

```
 py -3
```

to run Python 3. The launcher was created specifically because the name is always `python.exe` on Windows, so only one version could ever be found in the `PATH`; the launcher grants access to all installed copies without manipulating `PATH`. Doesn't even require extra typing (`py -2` being shorter than `python`).

Answer (score 0):

The Python installer installs [PyLauncher](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows) unless you deselected it.  **Don't** add python to the PATH.  `py.exe` (the launcher) is installed in the path already (C:\Windows by default).

```
py -2   # launches latest python 2 installed.
py -3   # launches latest python 3 installed.
py -3.6 # launches Python 3.6.
```

The `PY_PYTHON` environment variable can be set, e.g. `set PY_PYTHON=3.6` to select a default python when running just `py`; otherwise, it will choose the latest version of Python installed.

You can also use `#!python2` in a script for it to use that version of Python when double-clicked in Explorer or run without a specific switch (`py script.py`).